# PagerSlidingTabStrip isn't working, but my code seems OK to me

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've tried to implement PagerSlidingTabStrip to my app but it just isn't working. I did everything that is done in the [sample](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java#L59) but it isn't working. The tab indicator just isn't moving as it is supposed to and the app isn't crashing. Basically nothing is happening. I have no idea what is wrong.

**MainActivity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

ActionBar aBar;
ViewPager vPager;
PagerAdapter pAdapter;
PagerSlidingTabStrip slidingTabStrip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    // Action Bar
    aBar = getActionBar();
    aBar.setTitle("Beautiful Voice Recorder");
    aBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Variables    
    slidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.slidingTabs);
    vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Tabs     
    vPager.setAdapter(pAdapter);
    slidingTabStrip.setViewPager(vPager);

    aBar.addTab(aBar.newTab().setText("Record").setTabListener(this));
    aBar.addTab(aBar.newTab().setText("Library").setTabListener(this));

    vPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            LibraryFragment listViewFragment = (LibraryFragment)pAdapter.instantiateItem(vPager, 1);
            RecordFragment recordFragment = (RecordFragment)pAdapter.instantiateItem(vPager, 0);
            listViewFragment.updateComponents();
            // Pause mp if it's playing and tabs are switched just in case
            if (listViewFragment.mp.isPlaying())
            {
                listViewFragment.mp.pause();
                listViewFragment.playPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button_selector);
            }
            if (recordFragment.isRecording)
            {
                recordFragment.stopRecording();
            }
            aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    vPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

String[] pageTitles = { "Record", "Library" };  

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    if (arg0 == 0)
    {
        fragment = new RecordFragment();
    }
    if (arg0 == 1)
    {
        fragment = new LibraryFragment();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pageTitles.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return pageTitles[position];
}

}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone have any idea why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was lying after I took a deeper look at the sample code. The problem was the fact that I still had the previous **ActionBar tabs** left in the code and those were overlapping the **PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs** so that I didn't see them.

All I had to do was to remove every reference to ActionBar tabs and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't locate ViewPager even if it's RelativeLayout.

so try this code that i'm using. I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            />
    <com.flitto.app.widgets.MainViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            tools:context=".MainTabActivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In my case I was using LinearLayout. The above helped me